# How to discover where localhost points to?

Tags: windows, networking

I have the following link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:61374/wse/wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp?org.eclipse.wst.ws.explorer=0
```

Now since this starts with `127.0.0.1`, my browser is showing me a file that is in my computer. I want to learn where this file is.

To do so, I need to learn which directory `127.0.0.1:61374` points to. So, I ran:

```
netstat -ano
```

In the output:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:61374        127.0.0.1:63216        ESTABLISHED     7228
```

Then I ran:

```
tasklist
```

In the output:

```
javaw.exe                     7228 Console                    1    950.936 K
```

So a Java program is running behind this port. However, where do I go from here to discover where is the file `http://127.0.0.1:61374/wse/wsexplorer/wsexplorer.jsp?org.eclipse.wst.ws.explorer=0` in my computer?

I also tried searching the whole computer for `wse` but the search did not return any directory named `wse`. Is this normal?

Comment: It's not so simple. The process is java, which is running some java code. How that URL you requested is 'mapped' is entirely in the hands of that java code.

Comment: @Sobrique I also tried searching whole computer for `wse` but the search did not return any directory named `wse`. Is this normal?

Comment: Certainly. It is more likely the name of a web-app in some servlet or J2EE container.

Comment: Yes. The process listening to the port decides what `/wse/` relates to, or means. It _can_ map to a directory structure, and that's how it's traditionally done on webservers, but there's absolutely nothing to say it must (or indeed, should)